# Handle multiple tap gesture on stackviews

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, uistackview

I have three stackviews that I want to add tap gesture, here is my code, but I have to copy a same code again and again, cold you show me a better way to do that?

```
func addTapGestureToInformationLables(){
    let tapLanguage = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapLanguage(_:)))
    languageStack.addGestureRecognizer(tapLanguage)
    let tapFollower = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleFollowers(_:)))
    followrsStack.addGestureRecognizer(tapFollower)
    let tapFollowing = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleFollowing(_:)))
    followingStack.addGestureRecognizer(tapFollowing)
}



@objc func handleTapLanguage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "language", sender: nil)
}


@objc func handleFollowers(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "followers", sender: nil)
}


@objc func handleFollowing(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "following", sender: nil)
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to map the `UIStackView` to the `segue` `identifier` and then use a single `handleTap()` routine to look up the `identifier` using the `view` associated with the `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
var actions = [UIStackView : String]()

func addTapGestureToInformationLables(){
    actions = [languageStack: "language", followrsStack: "followers", followingStack: "following"]

    for stackview in actions.keys {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target, self, action: #selector(self.handleTap))
        stackview.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
}   

@objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let stackview = sender.view as? UIStackView,
          let identifier = actions[stackview]
        else { return }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: nil)
}
```